# Canvas Line Drawing Fails To Display

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am working on a very basic function learning how to use HTML5 Canvases. This code should generate a tree, but it fails to do so, can anyone provide any ideas?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script>
    function createCanopyPath(context) {

        context.beginPath();

        context.moveTo(-25, -50);
        context.lineTo(-10, -80);
        context.lineTo(-20, -80);
        context.lineTo(-5, -110);
        context.lineTo(-15, -110);

        context.lineTo(0, -140);

        context.lineTo(15, -110);
        context.lineTo(5, -110);
        context.lineTo(20, -80);
        context.lineTo(10, -80);
        context.lineTo(25, -50);

        context.closePath();

    }

function drawTrails() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('trails');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    context.save();
    context.translate(130, 250);

    createCanopyPath(context);

    context.stroke();
    context.restore();
}
</script>



<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>

<canvas id="diagonal" style="border: 1px solid;" height="200" width="200"></canvas>


</body> 
</html>
```

I would greatly appreciate any assistance.

Thank you.

Comment: You are getting the wrong canvas. `document.getElementById('trails')` should be `document.getElementById('diagonal')`

Comment: Still isn't working :(
I've coped this from a book verbatam, or so I believe.

Comment: Remove the function drawtrails() line and its opening and closing braces.

Comment: Maybe you should include 'window.addEventListener("load",drawTrails)` this will call the function to do the drawing as currently you have not called any functions. The event listener waits until the page loads because if you call the function from within the script tag the Canvas would not yet have been created as it is after the script.